# Retrieveing data from mysql using netbeans

Tags: mysql, javafx

I am creating a project named as "Library management system". The problem I am facing is that when I enter data into the textfield of ID to retrieve data from database (MySql) to show it on other "Text" than it shows nothing...

Can anyone guide me over this

In the Code:

**Bookidinput** = Textfield name
**Bookname**  = Text name of Book Title (Text means simple Javafx FXML Text)
**bookauthor** = Text name of Book author

```
package lms.ui.main;

import com.jfoenix.effects.JFXDepthManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
 import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import lms.database.databaseHandler;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private HBox book_info;
@FXML
private HBox member_info;
@FXML
private Text bookname;
@FXML
private Text bookauthor;
@FXML
private Text member_name;
@FXML
private Text member_email;
@FXML
private TextField bookidinput;
@FXML
private TextField memberidinput;

databaseHandler handler;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    JFXDepthManager.setDepth(book_info, 2);
    JFXDepthManager.setDepth(member_info, 2);

    handler = databaseHandler.getInstance();
}    

@FXML
private void AddNewMember(ActionEvent event) {

    loadWindow("/lms/ui/Add_Member/Add_Member.fxml", "Add New Member");
}

@FXML
private void AddNewBook(ActionEvent event) {

    loadWindow("/lms/FXML_AddBook.fxml", "Add New Book");
}

@FXML
private void ListMemberTable(ActionEvent event) {

    loadWindow("/lms/ui/ListMemberTable/MemberList.fxml", "Member 
Table");
}

@FXML
private void ListBooKTable(ActionEvent event) {

    loadWindow("/lms/ui/ListBookTable/BookList.fxml", "Book Table");
}

@FXML
private void Settings(ActionEvent event) {
}

    void loadWindow(String loc, String Title){

    try{
             Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(loc));
             Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
             stage.setTitle(Title);
             stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
             stage.show();

    }
    catch(IOException e){

 Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
 e);
    }
 }

 @FXML
 private void loadbookinfo(ActionEvent event) {

    String id = bookidinput.getText();
    String qu = "Select * from Books where ID = ' " + 
 bookidinput.getText() + " ' ";
    ResultSet rs = handler.exeQuery(qu) ;
   Boolean flag = false;
    try {
        while( rs.next())
        {
          String bName = rs.getString("Title");
          String bAuthor = rs.getString("Author");

          bookname.setText(rs.getString("Title"));
          bookauthor.setText(rs.getString("Author"));
          flag = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

 Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
 ex);
    }
 }
```

```sql
create table Books( ID varchar(30) primary key,
Title varchar(50),
 Author varchar (60),
 Publisher varchar(60));

insert into Books values(101, "ITM", "Stephen, Coulter, Vohra", "Bloomsbury Publishing Plc");
insert into Books values(102, "The C++ Programming Language",   "Bjarne Stroustrup", "Daastan");
insert into Books values(103, "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++", "Bjarne Stroustrup", "Pearson");
insert into Books values(104, "Modern C++ Design", "Andrei Alexandrescu", "Addison-Wesley");
insert into Books (ID,Title,Author,Publisher) values(105, "Effective C++", "Scott Meyers", "RELX Group");
```

I expect Book name to appear in "Text" but output is nothing.**strong text**

[image]

Comment: Don't you have a space after the opening single-quote delimiter and a space before the closing single-quote delimiter? Is that what you really want?

Comment: In addition to quoting the string yourself instead of using `PreparedStatement`, making your code vulnerable to sql injection, you add space chars to both ends of the input. If the `TextField` contains input `104`, the string literal in the sql query becomes `' 104 '` which is not the same as `'104'`. None of the ids in your db creation code starts or ends with space chars.

Comment: Did you write the class `lms.database.databaseHandler`? Are you sure that the SQL query `Select * from Books where ID = ?` returns at least one row? The data type for column ID in database table _Books_ is `varchar(30)`, yet in the INSERT statements the value for that column is always a number. Is that intentional?

Comment: Maybe you could post your `.fxml` file as well? Are you sure that method `loadbookinfo(ActionEvent)` is being called?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dALRmoZR1pY&list=PLhs1urmduZ29jTcE1ca8Z6bZNvH_39ayL&index=12                     i am following this tutorial on youtube...please check this out so you can have a better understanding of what i am doing . Thanks!

Comment: Not sure this is the best choice of tutorial. Even though overall it seems to be ok, there are several small issues I have with the code created in the tutorial: The use of reference type `Boolean` even though there is no chance of `null` being assigned to the variable, as mentioned not using `PreparedStatement` and last but not least the use of a `while` loop when the query is expected to return at most a single row, which could be written much simpler with `if(rs.next()) { ... retrieve book data... } else { ...inform user of book being unavailable... }`

Comment: From what I can tell, the code you posted for method `loadbookinfo()` is not the same as the code shown in the video.

Comment: Fabian i tried what you said and my code run successfully now. But still there is an issue and a question...I have already written data in database using WorkBench.When i try to retrieve that data which is written using workbench, it says "No such Book available" (error occura). But at the same time if i enter data into database using my AddBook.fxml file (i created in project but not displayed in queation) than book name and book author are displayed and code runs aucceaafully. Can u explain me why this is happening.